# xamarin iOS alasset fullresolution image with filter

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, alasset

I am working on a Xamarin IOS application, testing on a iPhone5 version 8.1.3, where I let the user select images with the ALAssetLibrary. These images get send to a server and get processed. There is a minimum size to these images so I need the complete image.

I have a bit of a problem with getting the full resolution images. 
First I check the size of the images with `asset.DefaultRepresentation.Dimensions`. After that I get the image with `asset.DefaultRepresentation.GetImage()`. Now here i have three different cases.

1. a image with no filter
2. a image made with a filter
3. a image made without a filter, and a filter later applied to it

In all three cases the dimensions give me a value like h:3500 w: 2800. Which is exactly what I need. When i get the images in the first and third case it gives me a image with the same size. But in the second case it gives me a image with something like h:910 w: 640; Which is the same size as `asset.DefaultRepresentation.GetFullScreenImage()` would give me.

Is there any way to get a full size image when the image is made with a filter?

**EDIT**

Also when I make a photo with a filter and then remove the filter from the image I get a image with h:3500 w:2800. This means that the original image must be present. I just need to know how to get it.

Comment: "The Assets Library framework is deprecated as of iOS 9.0. Instead, use the Photos framework instead, which in iOS 8.0 and later provides more features and better performance for working with a user’s photo library." (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/) Maybe you can avoid the problem by using the recommended Library?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Felix. I have indeed been working on implementing the Photos framework. This does give me the opportunity to get the original image without any filters. Now i need to find a way to make those images filtered without cropping.

Comment: What about Core Image Filters? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185